# Angular Material mdToast causing AngularJS Infinite $digest Loop

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-material

I have a Ruby on Rails web application that I am supplementing with AngularJS and Angular Material. I am trying to display an Angular Material toast notification on a webpage using a binding (this might be the problem). This is my first time working with AngularJS, so I have limited understanding of the inner-workings and best practices. A trial by fire, if you will.

Below is the JavaScript code for my Angular module and controller as well as the HTML wherein the problem occurs.

**JavaScript**

```
var app = angular.module('VisualLearning', [
    "ngAnimate",
    "ngMaterial",
    "ngMdIcons"
  ]);


app.controller("BodyController", ["$scope", "$mdSidenav", "$mdToast", function ($scope, $mdSidenav, $mdToast) {

    $scope.toggleSidenav = function (menuID) {
        $mdSidenav(menuID).toggle();
    };

    $scope.setToolbarTitle = function(title) {
        $('#toolbarTitle').html(title);
    };

    $scope.openToast = function(toastText) {
        var toast = $mdToast.simple().content(toastText).position("top right")
        $mdToast.show(toast);
    }

}]);
```

**HTML**

```
<body id="body" layout="row" ng-controller="BodyController">
  <% if session[:notify] %>
    {{openToast("This is a Test Toast!")}}
  <% session[:notify] = false %>
  <% end %>

  {{setToolbarTitle("Where To Next?")}}

  <md-content flex md-scroll-y>
    <ui-view layout="column">
      <div id="buttonContainer">

        <div class="buttons">

          <%= link_to :controller => :staff_users, :action => :show, :id => @current_user.id do %>
              <button class="button buttonBlue">My Account
                <div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div>
              </button>
          <% end %>

          <%= link_to :controller => :session, :action => :logout do %>
              <button class="button buttonBlue">Log Out
                <div class="ripples buttonRipples"><span class="ripplesCircle"></span></div>
              </button>
          <% end %>

        </div>
      </div>
    </ui-view>
  </md-content>
</body>
```

My toast notification appears, but I am not able to dismiss the toast. Furthermore, the error console reports an infinite $digest loop. From my understanding, Angular is using a $watch to continuously update the page based on changes to the model. With that, I am not sure why I am running into an infinite loop with the toast since I had the single toast, I display it, and never try to change it again. Is there something else that I am missing?

If I should not be using a binding here, what would the better solution be? I will also expand this question to include is it proper to use the binding to call a function to set the text of an element on the page as you see with setToolbarTitle? If not, I would appreciate guidance for proper style and convention.

Answer (score 1):

By doing

```
{{openToast("This is a Test Toast!")}}
```

In your template, you are asking angular to watch the execution return of the method call, evaluating it at every digest cycle. This is something you basically never want to do.

The correct way to show your toast would simply be to call if from your controller.

```
app.controller("BodyController", ["$scope", "$mdSidenav", "$mdToast", function ($scope, $mdSidenav, $mdToast) {

    $scope.toggleSidenav = function (menuID) {
        $mdSidenav(menuID).toggle();
    };

    $scope.setToolbarTitle = function(title) {
        $('#toolbarTitle').html(title);
    };

    $scope.openToast = function(toastText) {
        var toast = $mdToast.simple().content(toastText).position("top right")
        $mdToast.show(toast);
    }

    $scope.openToast("This is a Test Toast!");

}]);
```

Comment: The problem is that I need the toast to open conditionally based on a ruby variable. Do you know how I could accomplish this?